# Does MongoDB have a native REST interface?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest

I am currently evaluating Mongo and CouchDB for storing data points (analytics).

During my earlier interaction with CouchDB, I loved its JSONP based interface. I could perform all CRUD operations from purely JavaScript.
Just run CouchDB and write some JavaScript - no server side component needed.

When comparing this to Mongo, is there any REST interface available?
Is it possible to do CRUD purely from javascript in Mongo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no full-blown REST interface to MongoDB, mainly because the server uses native binary protocol for efficiency. You can find few REST wrappers in official [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) (edit: MongoDB inc has now deleted this information):

> - [RESTHeart](http://restheart.org) (Java 8) is a the data REST API server part of the MongoDB ecosystem. RESTHeart uses a standard representation format based on HAL with full native mongodb data support via the strict mode representation of BSON.
>   It provides API for CRUD and data model operations, built-in authentication and authorization and it supports CORS.
>   It is easy to setup and a docker container is available. RESTHeart is also fast  and lightweight (~7 Mb footprint and ~200 Mb RAM peek usage).

> - [Sleepy Mongoose](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/) (Python) is a full featured REST interface for MongoDB which is available as a separate project.

> - [Rest on Mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rest-on-mongo) for node.js. The older [MongoDB Rest](https://github.com/codecapers/mongodb-rest) is no longer maintained.

> - [Simple REST Interface](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api) The mongod process includes a simple read-only REST interface for convenience.  For full REST capabilities we recommend using an external tool such as [Sleepy.Mongoose](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/).

Comment: To enable Simple REST Interface specify `--rest` on the command line to mongod, or add `rest = true` within `mongodb.conf`, also to enable JSONP output you need `--jsonp` or `jsonp = true` and then you specify the name of the callback function as a request parameter like this `http://mymongodb.example.com/database/collection/?jsonp=myCallback`

Comment: the native --rest feature does not support CORS which limits the usefulness without a reverse proxy if your db is not local.

Comment: built-in rest interface has less use because of CORS issue

Comment: This solution is now outdated. Please see @sumedhamehta's solution for an update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386740/does-mongodb-have-a-native-rest-interface/70369916#70369916

Answer (score 23):

The [MongoDB Atlas Data API in Preview](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/data-api/) was also released in November 2021 to use with a hosted MongoDB instance through the company's [Atlas offering](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/). It lets you send complex queries and aggregations to MongoDB over a standard HTTPS interface, though it isn't currently recommended for direct client-side access.

For instance, once a cluster is created and the Data API is enabled for it, the following request can be used to insert a document -

```
  curl --request POST \
  'https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/<Unique ID>/endpoint/data/beta/action/insertOne' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: *' \
  --header 'api-key: <Data API Key>' \
  --data-raw '{
      "dataSource": "Cluster0",
      "database": "todo",
      "collection": "tasks",
      "document": {
        "status": "open",
        "text": "Do the dishes"
      }
  }'
```

and the following to do an aggregation -

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/<Unique ID>/endpoint/v1/beta/action/aggregate' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: *' \
--header 'api-key:<Data API Key>' \
--data-raw '{
    "collection":"movies",
    "database":"sample_mflix",
    "dataSource": "Cluster0",
    "pipeline": [
  {
    "$search": {
      "index": "default",
      "text": {
        "query": "Brad Pitt",
        "path": {
          "wilcard": "*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

Both the API and Atlas offer free tiers and only take a few minutes to spin up.

Full disclosure - I work for MongoDB, Inc.

Comment: Will there be any major breaking changes in GA? If I use the Data API(preview) in production, will it break when the GA comes?

Comment: On prem it can't work, where you don't have internet access

Answer (score 9):

Another option (shameless plug) is **[DrowsyDromedary](https://github.com/zuk/DrowsyDromedary)**.

We developed Drowsy out of frustration with the other REST options for Mongo. Namely, we found that:

**Sleepy Mongoose** is not really RESTful. It's a hacky HTTP interface that does not follow REST conventions; it doesn't use the standard REST HTTP methods, it doesn't use URLs to properly identify resources... We also found the options for limiting the maximum number of results (which is limited by default) rather confusing.

**mongodb-rest** offers a proper REST interface, but we found it to be a pain in the ass to run. It would die regularly, and drove our sysadmin insane (who admittedly has little experience running node.js services).

The **built-in REST interface** would have been great, but it being read-only means it's mostly useless for our needs.

**DrowsyDromedary**, was developed to address many of the above issues:

1. It provides a conventional REST interface, with support for the standard HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH).
2. It's fairly easy to install and deploy (clone from github, install bundler, run `bundle`, and then `rackup`, and you're running). It can also be easily deployed under Apache or nginx.

Comment: hu never seen a ?(shameless plug)' most well wantedthan this, since __DrowsyDromedary__ deserves more AAA's. I liked and installed just of the 'Camel' affinity, but it paid me much. I currently used it on production, and it have a super fast , super dev friendly approach. love u LOL. this should be the best

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**

[Python Eve](http://python-eve.org/) is a fantastic solution for this. I have found it very easy to use and highly configurable.

> Eve is an open source Python REST API framework designed for human
>   beings. It allows to effortlessly build and deploy highly
>   customizable, fully featured RESTful Web Services.
>
> Eve is powered by Flask, Redis, Cerberus, Events and offers support
>   for both MongoDB and SQL backends [*].
>
> The codebase is thoroughly tested under Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 and
>   PyPy.

It is as simple to get started as:

```
from eve import Eve

app = Eve()
app.run()
```

and to use as

```
$ curl -i http://example.com/people
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

REST endpoint schemas are easily defined in a settings file.

**Original**

I haven't used it yet, but [RESTHeart](http://restheart.org/) looks like an answer to this.

From the documentation it looks easy to set up and use.

Answer (score 2):

mongodb-rest's fork by ActibeUnits ([github repo](https://github.com/ActiveUnits/mongodb-rest)) is one of the fastest and most feature rich rest interface to mongodb that I've seen.

I would highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The mongod process includes [a simple read-only REST interface](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) for convenience.  For full REST capabilities you need to use an external tool such as Sleepy.Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

[RESTHeart](http://restheart.org) is a the new data REST API server part of the MongoDB ecosystem.

It provides [API](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/GICM) for CRUD and data model operations, built-in authentication and authorization and supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin__resource__sharing%22CORS).

It uses a standard [representation format](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/UICM) based on [HAL+json](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) with full support of the native mongodb data format via the strict mode representation of BSON.

It is easy to [setup](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/FICM) and a [docker container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/softinstigate/restheart/) is available.

RESTHeart is fast (see [performance test result](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/gICM)) and lightweight (~7 Mb footprint and ~200 Mb RAM peek usage).

Answer (score 0):

No. But *mongodb-rest* is moving forward now.

https://github.com/codecapers/mongodb-rest