# BaseX GUI and MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, user-interface, basex

[BaseX](http://basex.org/products/) focuses on storing, querying, and visualizing large XML and **JSON** documents and collections.

Is there any way to query MongoDB documents and use BaseX visualizing ability?

Comment: Have you tried the JSON module?

Comment: @WiredPrairie No. Can it send query to MongoDB server?

Comment: Not directly (at least not in a straightforward way). It's really designed for XML, so JSON needs to be transformed into XML. http://docs.basex.org/wiki/JSON_Module

Comment: Use the JSON module like WiredPrairie proposed and have a look at the different [MongoDB-Rest-Wrappers proposed in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386740/does-mongodb-has-a-native-rest-interface), so you can use BaseX' HTTP module to connect to MongoDB.

Comment: Just to complement this. We are currently working on the specification of an XQuery MongoDB Module: http://expath.org/spec/mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help, the information comes from: http://docs.basex.org/wiki/JSON

Example: Converts a JSON string with simple objects and arrays
Query:

```
json:parse('{
 "title": "Talk On Travel Pool",
 "link": "http://www.flickr.com/groups/talkontravel/pool/",
 "description": "Travel and vacation photos from around the world.",
 "modified": "2014-02-02T11:10:27Z",
 "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/"
 }')
```

Result:

```
 <json type="object">
   <title>Talk On Travel Pool</title>
   <link>http://www.flickr.com/groups/talkontravel/pool/</link>
   <description>Travel and vacation photos from around the world.    </description>
   <modified>2014-02-02T11:10:27Z</modified>
   <generator>http://www.flickr.com/</generator>
```